# DIV tags changing size depending on content

Tags: css, html, tags

I'm in the process of playing with HTML and CSS. I have the following at the moment:

```
/*Reset margins & padding*/
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, div, ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

#divWrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#divHeader {
    width: 100%;
    background: #CC0000;
    text-align: center;

    /* Margins */
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

    /* Radius */
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#divMenuStrip {
    width: 100%;
    background: #646464;
    text-align: center;

    /* Margins */
    margin-top: 10px;

    /* Padding */
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;


    /* Radius */
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#divContent {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;

    /* Margins */
    margin-top: 10px;

    /* Padding */
    padding: 8px;

    /* Radius */
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

AND...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="divWrapper">

                <div id="divHeader"><img src="./images/headers/header-1.jpg" /></div>
                <div id="divMenuStrip">This is where the menu will be displayed</div>   
                <div id="divContent">This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed. This is where the content will be displayed.  </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I load up the HTML page in my web browser it appears as though depending on the amount of content within the div tags that are text are affecting my div tag's size.

Can anybody shed light as to why this is? Thanks!!!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? By their nature, divs and other such elements expand to accommodate their contents. (Avoid setting a height on them, as suggested above. That's a recipe for layout disaster, in most cases.)

Comment: Set height for what sorry? I want to limit the whole site's content to 90% of the page (As the wrapper is set to 90%). I then want every other div to then to be the full width. That's 90% of the whole screen res.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6zLbC/

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment I want to keep the width the same. The link that Shibin Ragh has posted to shows what I am talking about. The red is smaller, than the grey than that white. I want them all to be 90% of the screen width. I know how I would do that with a table but can I do it with a div?

Answer (score 1):

This is how divs behave by default. If you want it to show a certain height, you will have to specify it with

```
height:XXpx;
```

The reason behind this is content these days are dynamic i.e changes a lot, with time. it would be cumbersome to change height manually every time the content changes.

Comment: Sorry but does anybody else have a response?? :-)

Comment: I went through your comments and I think I got your question wrong. Could you explain what exactly your looking for?? Is it the height or the width that you want fixed???